# How to use javascript if statements within function to populate table

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I've created a search page that sends results to a table with the ability to click on a specific record which then opens another page in the desired format.

I'd like to do is be able to open different formatted pages based on the data returned in the search query but I'm having a bit of trouble pulling it all together.

Here's the PHP used to request and retrieve the data from the database, as well as populate it in a table where each record can be selected and used to populate a planner page with all the proper formatting:

```
$search = $_POST['search'].'%';
$ment = $_POST['ment'];

    $stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT lname, fname, rank, reserve, ment1, pkey FROM planner WHERE lname LIKE ? AND ment1 LIKE ? ORDER BY lname, fname");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $search, $ment);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><th>Last Name</th><th>First Name</th><th>Rank</th><th>Mentor Group</th><th></th></tr>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rsv = $row['reserve'];
    $pkey = $row['pkey'];
        echo "<tr><td>".$row['lname']."</td><td>".$row['fname']."</td><td>".$row['rank']."</td><td>".$row['ment1']."</td><td><button onClick=getPlanner('".$pkey."');>Get Planner</button></td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

} else {
    echo "0 results";

}
```

Now the fun part.  I want to open different pages based on the information contained in the record.  I've got it working for the pkey variable by itself with a single javascript function.  However, if I want to open a differently formatted page using the same function using if, else statements, the table only populates with the link page based on the last record compared.  Here is my attempt to get the JavaScript with the if, else statements working but it only uses the format of the last record that's compared.

```
var pkey = <?php echo json_encode($pkey); ?>;
var rsv = <?php echo $rsv ?>;

//var check = document.write(rsv);

function getPlanner(pkey) {
  if(rsv != 0){
    var plan = window.open("../php/plannerR.php?pln=" + pkey);
  } else {
    var plan = window.open("../php/planner.php?pln=" + pkey);
}
}
```

How do I get the 'Get Planner' button to open the correctly formatted planner page based on the users specific information?

Comment: you should pass both pkey _and_ rsv to the function.

Comment: so something like ... function getPlanner(pkey rsv)   ???

Comment: Hmm... still get the same result.

Comment: change `onClick=getPlanner('".$pkey."');` to `onClick=getPlanner('".$pkey."',".$rsv." );` _and_ `function getPlanner(pkey)` to `function getPlanner(pkey, rsv)`. No need for the `var = pkey=...` and `var rsv=...` before then.

Comment: but all this can be accomplished much easier directly in php. unless you have further need for a js function I'd recommend that.

Comment: also think twice if it _really_ has to be 2 seperate pages, or if one script (that generates different output depending on rsv) with an additional parameter `&rsv=0' would be an option.

Comment: Thanks Jeff.  Really appreciate the help.

Comment: If my solution helped, you might want to consider accepting my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make things easier I'd suggest the following:
Do the logic already in php when generating the html-table (and the link).

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rsv = $row['reserve'];
    $pkey = $row['pkey'];
    if($rsv) { // thats basicly the same as !=0
        $target='../php/plannerR.php'
    } else {
        $target='../php/planner.php'
    }
    echo "<tr><td>".$row['lname']."</td><td>".$row['fname']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$row['rank']."</td><td>".$row['ment1']."</td>";
    echo "<td><a class='button styleIt' href='".$target."?pkey=".$pkey."&rsv=".$rsv."'>Get Planner</a></td></tr>";
}
```

If you wanna stick to your js solution (which is more hassle unless you really need it) you can of course go with the solution from my comments that you already successfully implemented (and posted as answer so others can see the implementetion).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Jeff I played around a bit with bringing both variables into the function and got it to work.  Final code below.

```
$search = $_POST['search'].'%';
$ment = $_POST['ment'];

    $stmt = $link->prepare("SELECT lname, fname, rank, reserve, ment1, pkey FROM planner WHERE lname LIKE ? AND ment1 LIKE ? ORDER BY lname, fname");
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $search, $ment);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table><tr><th>Last Name</th><th>First Name</th><th>Rank</th><th>Mentor Group</th><th></th></tr>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $rsv = $row['reserve'];
    $pkey = $row['pkey'];
        echo "<tr><td>".$row['lname']."</td><td>".$row['fname']."</td><td>".$row['rank']."</td><td>".$row['ment1']."</td><td><button onClick=getPlanner('".$pkey."','".$rsv."');>Get Planner</button></td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

} else {
    echo "0 results";

}



var pkey = <?php echo json_encode($pkey); ?>;
var rsv = <?php echo $rsv ?>;

//var check = document.write(rsv);
function getPlanner(pkey, rsv) {
if(rsv != 0){
var plan = window.open("../php/plannerR.php?pln=" + pkey);
}
else{
var plan = window.open("../php/planner.php?pln=" + pkey);
}
}
```